# Were my actions with this suggested edit sufficient?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam

I recently came upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25246856) by an anonymous user. The edit inserted two images which weren't present in the original post, and removed emphasis from some text. On first glance the images didn't contain any additional information. The comment was in Arab letters and therefore didn't help explain the reason for the change, so I decided to reject with the reason

> no improvement whatsoever

Later I noticed that two other reviewers had approved the edit and I decided to give it another look and got the suspicion that the images could be meant as spam. I therefore rolled that edit back.

Since the edit was proposed by an anonymous user a moderator can't do anything against them. Should I flag this and probably other similar edits for moderator attention anyway?

Comment: I can't believe that 2 people approved that edit; they clearly aren't actually checking... Considering one has a reject ratio of 0.8%, perhaps they aren't.

Comment: A moderator can issue review suspensions, which would be very appropriate for the people approving that edit. And I'm not entirely sure, but I think there are tools to limit spam edits from anonymous users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Where my actions with this suggested edit sufficient?

Rolling it back was good.

---

> But should I flag this and probably other similar edits for moderator attention anyway?

Yes.

That was a rubbish edit and a moderator should review the history of the two people who approved it.

---

> The comment was in [Arabic] letters and therefore didn't help.

For what it's worth, Google translates the edit reason as *"Shalila Platform, Riyadh, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia"*. Very informative.

Comment: Thanks for the claification. I just raised the Mod flag on the question.